# Converting input as adjectives in String to numbers in Float in python

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am trying to code in python so that the user can type either good or bad, then the code converts the user input to a number- good = 0.7 and bad = 0.3. Then, I want to the code to calculate a weighted geometric mean (this part I am happy with what I have.)

My issue is that I can't get the user inputs of 'good' and 'bad' to convert from str to float so that I can calculate the geometric mean of the user input. I put what I coded below as well as the result it produces. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
mydict = {'good':0.7, 'bad':0.3}
print('Bid Number 1')
num1 = input('Cost Score:')
num2 = input('Past Performance Score:')
num3 = input('Quality Score:')
num4 = input('Management Capability:')
num5 = input('Innovation Score:')
num6 = input('Corporate Compliance:')
a = float( num1 ) * float( num1 ) * float( num1) *float( num2 ) * float( num3 ) *float( num4 ) * float( num5 ) * float( num5 ) * float( num6 )
b = 1/9
print( 'Bid Number 1 Score:', a ** b , sep = '')
```

User input:

```
>Bid Number 1
>Cost Score:good
>Past Performance Score:good
>Quality Score:bad
>Management Capability:bad
>Innovation Score:good    
>Corporate Compliance:bad
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brianhaney/Documents/Stack Example.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = float( num1 ) * float( num1 ) * float( num1) *float( num2 ) * float( num3 ) *float( num4 ) * float( num5 ) * float( num5 ) * float( num6 )
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'good'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use the dictionary

```
float(mydict[num1])
```

Or, using a default value for incorrect input

```
num1 = mydict.get(input('Cost Score:'), '0')
```

Repeat for all the values.

P.S. Use a list instead of numbered variables

Comment: You are the man! Thanks so much!! I spent 4 hours trying to figure that out yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the contents of the dictionary. For example:

```
mydict = {'good':0.7, 'bad':0.3}
print('Bid Number 1')
num1 = input('Cost Score:')
num2 = input('Past Performance Score:')
num3 = input('Quality Score:')
num4 = input('Management Capability:')
num5 = input('Innovation Score:')
num6 = input('Corporate Compliance:')
#a = float( mydict[num1] ) * float( mydict[num1] ) * float( mydict[num1]) *float( mydict[num2] ) * float(mydict[num3] ) *float( mydict[num4] ) * float( mydict[num5] ) * float( mydict[num5] ) * float( mydict[num6] )
a = mydict[num1]  *  mydict[num1]  *  mydict[num1] *  mydict[num2]  * mydict[num3] * mydict[num4] * mydict[num5] * mydict[num5]*  mydict[num6]
b = 1/9
print( 'Bid Number 1 Score:', a ** b , sep = '')
```

Note that the commented line would just be a change to your example, which could be better written as my code example and would have the same result.